# Gurobipy DLL load failed

Tags: python-2.7, dll, windows-10, 64-bit, gurobi

When trying to import gurobipy i get the following ImportError:

```
D:\Development\Anaconda3\envs\hiwi\python.exe D:/Development/Hiwi/Project_Code_Source/experiment/demo/run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Development/Hiwi/Project_Code_Source/experiment/demo/run.py", line 2, in <module>
    import experiment.demo.scenarios as scenarios
  File "D:\Development\Hiwi\Project_Code_Source\experiment\demo\scenarios.py", line 15, in <module>
    import framework.simu.ins_gen_v3 as insgen
  File "D:\Development\Hiwi\Project_Code_Source\framework\simu\ins_gen_v3.py", line 10, in <module>
    from gurobipy import *
  File "D:\Development\Anaconda3\envs\hiwi\lib\site-packages\gurobipy\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .gurobipy import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden. (English: Module not found.)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Since searching google resulted in errors related to environment variables and 64 vs 32 bit Versions i checkt those.

1. I am running the 64 bit Versions of Annaconda (3.6 using a 2.7 env) on Windows 10 and Gurobi
2. Gurobi is installed according to this instruction (including the license): http://www.gurobi.com/downloads/get-anaconda
3. The `GUROBI_HOME` variable is correctly set to `C:\gurobi702\win64` and the `Path` variable to `C:\gurobi702\win64\bin`
4. Python Path variables are set.
5. Following packages are installed: gurobi 7.5.1, mkl 2017.0.3, numpy 1.13.1, pip 9.0.1, python 2.7.13, setuptools 27.2.0, vs2008_runtime 9.00.30729.5054, wheel 0.29.0, wsgiref 0.1.2
6. Starting the gurobi console via cmd `gurobi` works fine.
7. I reinstalled my complete python environment multiple times and tried restarting after installation.

Comment: Try the full install and running `python setup.py install` from the GUROBI_HOME directory.

Comment: Sadly also not working. Could it be related to my conda environment  or that the environment and guroby are located on different drives?

Comment: Create a new environment (with anaconda-base packages, no full clone incl. gurobi and co), do the install-approach mentioned by Greg (no use of any anaconda-based binaries to setup gurobi) and if that's not working, post all the steps you did exactly! (as something like ```python C:\my_path\gurobi\setup.py install``` is enough to break it = not called from GUROBI_HOME directory). I never had issues with this kind of install on multiple occasions (also using anaconda) and i don't think the drive-diffence matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it running with a new conda environment and installing via `python setup.py install`, as mentioned by Greg Glockner and sascha.

Answer (score 1):

This problem [from .gurobipy import] is caused from the IDE Pycharm on Ubuntu. I am not sure if you may face it with the other IDEs . 
First You can make sure from the shell the python has gurobipy installed. 
after you installed from the file Gurobi ~\gurobi752\win64

```
python setup.py install
```

then just run python from the shell as normal python command 
`python yourFileName.py` and gurobi will works perfectly

In windows 10 i added the path of gurobi to the IDE pycharm
after `python setup.py install` and pip tool for gurobipy https://sites.google.com/site/pydatalog/python/pip-for-windows, then i added the path 
Settings->Project Interpreter-> show all -> interpreter paths -> add your gurobi path

I hope it works cheers ;)